# Javascript: Error in String Concatenation

Tags: string, double, concatenation, quotes

So I have this javascript function:

```
function show_courseline (course_index, repeats) {
var s = ""; 
var count = 0;
while (count < repeats) {
    s = s + 'Number: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'a').innerHTML + '\n' +
          'Semester: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'b').innerHTML + '\n' +
          'Year: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'c').innerHTML + '\n' +
          'Title: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'd').innerHTML + '\n' +
          'Units: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'e').innerHTML + '\n' +
          'Description: ' + document.getElementById(course_index + count + 'f').innerHTML + '\n';
    ++count;
}
alert(s);
}
```

But I get an error when I run it through an "onclick" input box. It has nothing to do with the document ids not being there, because they are.

Comment: What error messages do you get? Your second example works.

Comment: Oops, nevermind, the second example erred on something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is course_index  integer? If it is course_index + count is an integer and I know that ids cannot start with a digit

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! Thanks! So why can't ID's start with digits?

Comment: It is related to the languages' grammar and compiler issues. Most of the programming languages are designed in such a way.

Comment: @zitta: This isn't completely correct. In HTML5, the only restrictions on `id` are uniqueness and consisting of one or more characters that aren't spaces.